# Java: Simple Recursion Issue

Tags: java, if-statement, recursion, char, return

I'm extremely new to the whole idea of recursion, and it's blowing my mind a bit to be honest. I'm trying to turn this function I wrote into a recursive one...

```
public static int to_number(String s)
{
    int total = 0;
    int n=s.length();
    for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++) { 
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isDigit(c)){
            int value=Character.getNumericValue(c);
            total +=value;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(total);
    return total;
}
```

It reads in a string, such as "3aaa6a3", iterates through the string, if the `char` is a digit, it adds it to total, and so on. What I have so far...

```
    public static int to_number(String s)
{
    int total = 0;
    int n=s.length();
    int i=0;
    if (i == n){
        return 0; //if gone through the whole string
    }
    char c = s.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isDigit(c)){
            int value=Character.getNumericValue(c);
            total +=value;
        }

    System.out.println(total);
    i++;
    to_number(); //trying to call the same function
    return total;
}
```

I feel like I'm close, but just not getting it. Thanks for your time and effort!

Comment: At first glance that's not going to compile.  You're trying to call the `to_number(String)` method with no parameters.

Comment: Well, what's the actual problem you're facing?

Comment: @dguay passing `s` will cause infinite recursion.  The OP needs to pass a substring of `s`.

Comment: @azurefrog You're right my bad !

Comment: You should pass the string and current index that you are looking at to fetch the character to the function. Start with index = 0 and increment in each call. That way `if ( i == n)` will make sense. You should be able to proceed with this tip

Comment: Also notice that you are resetting total to 0.  It won't accumulate this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
public void intToNum(String s, int total[])
{

     if(s.isEmpty())
        return;

     char c = s.charAt(0);

if (Character.isDigit(c)){
            int value=Character.getNumericValue(c);
            total[0] +=value;
        }

intToNum(s.substring(1),total);

}
```

and in your main, call the function as

```
int [] total = new int[1];

intToNum(input,total);

System.out.println(total[0]);
```

or another approach is

public int intToNum(String s)
    {

```
     if(s.isEmpty())
        return 0;

     char c = s.charAt(0);

if (Character.isDigit(c)){

            int value=Character.getNumericValue(c);

            return value + intToNum(s.substring(1));
        }

return intToNum(s.substring(1));

}
```

Comment: wouldn't it be much easier to simply pass the total back as the output of the method?

Comment: why is total an array?

Comment: Yes, I was curious as to why you put total as an array?

Comment: for pass by reference. we want the array to persist across all of the recursions

Comment: if i just put an int, it will keep on getting overwritten

Comment: He's doing that to make it an in/out parameter, so method can be tail-recursive. Since Java doesn't do tail-recursion optimization, it's rather meaningless, and should just `return` the value instead. Even with tail-recursion, it's not "functional" coding since it updates a value, and should instead take the sumSoFar as a parameter and return the updated sum.

Comment: wouldn't you have to add an array to the call of intToNum as well and not just a string?

Comment: Okay I see what ya did now, not the way I was thinking of doing it, but hey its a start to my recursive learning! Thanks I really appreciate it!

Comment: glad to help :) all the best

Answer (score 1):

Not gonna give you the code, but as a recursive function, you want to process the first character of the input string, then call yourself with the remaining string, i.e. `to_number(s.substring(1))`, and combine the result. Recursion ends when input string is empty.

Answer (score 0):

This answer contains the solution. Just look at it when you are stuck. I also encourage you to read and understand the code instead of just copying it. **This is one of the most important concepts in programming, so make sure you understand it and are familiar with it.** :)

How it works: The method receives a string. If the string is longer than 1 character, the method splits it in half, calls itself on the two substrings and adds the two results. Those calls will do the same thing, until the string fragments are only 1 (or 0) characters long. In that case, it just returns their value (or 0, if there is no value).

```
public class RecursionVsIteration {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "2.938fyfh0293urhp2398rpod8723uoihr98y";
        System.out.println("Iterative: " + toNumberIterative(str));
        System.out.println("Recursive: " + toNumberRecursive(str));
    }

    public static int toNumberIterative(String s) {
        int total = 0;
        int n = s.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            char c = s.charAt(i);
            if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
                int value = Character.getNumericValue(c);
                total += value;
            }
        }
        return total;
    }

    public static int toNumberRecursive(String s) {
        int n = s.length();
        // termination criteria
        if (n == 0) { // emtpy string
            return 0;
        }
        if (n == 1) { // on character string
            char c = s.charAt(0);
            return Character.isDigit(c) ? Character.getNumericValue(c) : 0;
        }

        // recursive call (split the string in half and call the method on both substrings)
        return toNumberRecursive(s.substring(0, n / 2)) + toNumberRecursive(s.substring(n / 2, n));
    }
}
```